# How to remove (uninstall) XP-Pen Star G640 tablet on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: uninstall, tablet

Everytime I start my Ubuntu session, a window pop-up fires asking to connect and configure my tablet. Now I am using a Wacom one, and no longer need it.

Is there any way to remove or uninstall Star G640 XP-Pen tablet from my Ubuntu?
My current version is 22.04

Here where i found the driver i have installed https://www.xp-pen.es/download-204.html

I searched in the installed packages in my OS, but i don't found any package that has the name starting with xp-pen or pentablet.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled that like this. Check if the package is installed:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep xp-pen
```

Then I removed the package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r xp-pen-pentablet
```